# Laptop display flicks like a liquid inside when moving the lid

Tags: laptop, display, dell-inspiron, laptop-repair, laptop-display

My newly bought dell 3537 laptop accidentally hit on the wall and Now in that corner the display flicks like water inside when I move the laptop lid upwards.
Is this happens because of damage happened to the display?
How can I fix this?

Comment: Is it a liquid crystal display?...  Sorry, couldn't help but ask.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, this is because of damage to the display. Either an internal crack, a separation of layers, or perhaps the frame was bent or cracked causing pressure on the display panel (same effect as when you press on the screen with your finger).

Inspect the area closely for signs of physical damage. If the frame is bent and is metal, you could attempt to carefully unbend it but take care not to cause additional damage. If it is cracked and is plastic, perhaps you could locate the offending damage and pop it back into place; again taking great care. In my experience, though, these kinds of things are sometimes difficult or impossible to quickly repair, especially more subtle damage (e.g. bent frame or screws or hinges).

As a guess, it sounds to me like some part of the mounting frame was bent or separated near one of the hinges, or the hinge itself was bent causing some torque and pressure on that corner.

If you cannot easily identify the problem and fix it by hand, then the only way to fix would be to replace the damaged part - either the frame, hinges, or the display panel. An experienced repairman might be able to repair it by hand depending on the problem; which would be cheaper than ordering replacement parts -- but check your warranty status.

I suggest giving it a quick look, and if a fix isn't obvious to you, then check the warranty terms and contact the vendor that sold you the laptop for repair options. Either that or you will just have to live with it (but be warned, certain types of damage could just lead to further damage over time, you'd have to make that call). If your warranty covers it and the damage doesn't bother you, you could live it with it for some time as an experiment and then take it for repair if it gets worse (just do it before the warranty runs out). It's not going to hurt your data or anything like that; it's just a display issue.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. :) I checked the frame from outside and there is no visible bend or a dislocation from outside other than a scratch mark. 
When lid is open these is no flicking happens. So is there any possibility display panel to be damaged.

Comment: @user3673406 It's hard to say. It could certainly be damaged. To me it sounds like something is bent and putting pressure, perhaps too subtle for the eye to see, or on the inside. But it definitely could be a small crack in the panel itself, or a split between the layers. There's no way to tell for sure without taking it apart, unfortunately.